# Де "необхідно" є необхідним?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

У книзі [О.Курило "Уваги до української літературної мови"](http://kurylo.wikidot.com/23-deiaki-khybno-vzhyvani-slova) маємо таке зауваження:

> Дуже поширеним від недавнього словам необхідний, необхідно, необхідність надано в сучасній літературній мові такого широкого значіння, якого є відповідні російські слова — «необходимый, необходимо, необходимость». Уживають їх і там, **де нема того необхідного**. Кажуть необхідно зробити, — де має бути: треба зробити; замість необхідна умова краще й достотніше — невідмінна умова; кажуть — нема необхідности, де можна нема потреби чи просто не треба. Російське «необходимый» має деякими своїми відтінками ще відповідники (крім уже наведених) в українській мові, що можуть у потребі деталізувати те загальне поняття, яке сучасна мова вкладає в слово необхідний. Такі відповідники є доконечний, конечний, неминучий.

В Російсько-українських словниках до наведених слів як віповідник пропонується і прислівник *необхідно*. Тож у яких випадках його вживання буде доречним?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## За позицію Курило

Я припускаю, що Олена Курило виходить з етимології і побудови слова «необхідно». Мовляв, «той, що його **неможливо** обійти» (чи то «без якого не можна обійтись»?). Відповідно, «необхідно» видається **більш жорстким (квазі)синонімом** до слова «потрібно», а не просто синонімом.

Якщо навмисне тримати в голові буквальну інтерпретацію, то особисто для мене:

- «необхідно зробити» звучить якось дивно (і крім того не завжди відповідає суті: часто цим словосполученням позначають просто те, що *було вирішено зробити*, незалежно від того, чи *є альтернативні шляхи можливими*) — «потрібно/треба зробити» звучить зрозуміліше;
- «нема необхідності» (окрім викривлення буквального значення слова) ще й місить непотрібний повтор «не… не…».

І «Словник української мови» в 11 томах перші значення слів подає так:

> [НЕОБХІ́ДНИЙ](http://sum.in.ua/s/neobkhidnyj), а, е. 1. Без якого неможливо обійтися; **конче** потрібний. <…>
>
> [НЕОБХІ́ДНО](http://sum.in.ua/s/neobkhidno), присудк[ове] сл[ово]. **Конче** потрібно… <…>

## Проти позиції Курило

Але я не можу сказати, що Олена Курило на 100% права. Адже значення слів часто змінюються, зокрема іноді всупереч етимології (іноді навіть трапляється обернення значення на протилежне). І той же «Словник української мови» про слово «потрібно» продовжує далі:

> …конче потрібно, **є потреба**

(просто «є потреба», без усіляких «доконечна»/«крайня»/«сильна» — і це в тому ж першому значенні, не після цифри «2»). А стаття слова «[необхідність](http://sum.in.ua/s/neobkhidnistj)» не містить навіть і натяку на сильний ступінь чи непозбувність:

> 1. Потреба в чому-небудь. <…>
> 2. *філос[офія]*. Об'єктивний закономірний зв'язок між явищами матеріального світу, який випливає з самої природи речей, розкриває їх суттєві риси. <…>